# Foreign key constraint fails Entity_Type_ID

Tags: database, eav, magento2.2.3, foreign-key

Transferring my website database from 1.9.2.2 to 2.2.3 is successful. 
However if I then export and import again my database with **foreign key checks enabled** the below error is displayed.

> -- Constraints for table `eav_entity_store`
>   -- ALTER TABLE `eav_entity_store`   ADD CONSTRAINT `EAV_ENTITY_STORE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type`
>   (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,   ADD CONSTRAINT
>   `EAV_ENTITY_STORE_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`)
>   REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
>
> MySQL said:
>   **#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`#sql-44f8_43`, CONSTRAINT
>   `EAV_ENTITY_STORE_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`)
>   REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

As I understand EAV_ENTITY_STORE is the increment of ID's for orders, invoices, credit memos and shipments. The foreign key relates to eav_entity_type which defines the type of entity

5 = Order
6 = Invoice
7 = Credit memo
8 = Shipment

[image: magento eav_entity_store]

I only have one store on the new website

[image]

Is the problem that there is no longer store_id=2 and is it safe to just delete this? 
I know i could just import with **foreign key checks disabled** but I would like to avoid doing this as it normally creates problems later.

Comment: is it the complete error log ? i think this issue is related to `orphan` tables ,, if yes than have a look https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/213

Comment: hi yes it is the complete error log, migration is successful so i don't think it is related to that, I appreciate your help though